# How can I make the FooterView of a UITableView collapse?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a tableview that has a footer view that I need to expand and collapse programatically. If I set `Hidden` to `true` on the FooterView, it hides, but still occupies the space on the UI. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

They way that I solved it was setting the footer view of the table to a new UIView with an empty rectangle.